# Get the HTML output from an Angular template in javascript

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-template

I have an angular template that I would like to be able to access the processed HTML from within a javascript function.

If for example the template was under a templateUrl

```
 "/scheduler/tooltip.html"
```

and the HTML was something like

```
 <div>{{tip.Name}}</div>
```

is the a way to call and process that template without using all of the directive overhead?
eg:

```
 angular.$compiletemplate('/scheduler/tooltip.html', { tip: { Name: "foo" }});
```

In this case I'm specifically trying to solve the problem of a third party library appending a DOM element outside of the existing angular scope - so I *seem* to be unable to make the HTML a directive.

If there is a way to make sure a directive will work anywhere on the page that might also be useful.

Comment: Once your directive compiles, you can do something like element.html() to get the result

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps:

```
app.directive('yourDirective', function ($interval) {

    var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {

        var contents = element.html(); // this gets element HTML, initial HTML
        var currentContents = element.html();
        function updateContents() {
            currentContents = element.html();
            if(currentContents.length > contents.length)
                console.log('contents changed');
        }

        var interval = $interval(reportChange, 1000);

    }

});
```

Comment: as for a third party javascript running and inserting things into the DOM, you might just have to create an interval and have it report changes every few seconds

Comment: if you expect changes to variables on the scope in the directive, you can create a scope.$watch function to report the changes in html and see if something has been inserted